# How to use VLOOK to find text value in column 2 and return the text value in column one, which is right next to the found value

Tags: excel

In table A, I tried to use `=VLOOKUP(A2,VS!$A1:$B99,1,FALSE)` to see if there is a match in table VS. If there is a match I want to return the text value which is in the column next to the match value. But all the returned results are #N/A.

I'm not sure if I explain my question clearly. If not, please let me know and I will update my question.

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. Also, I want to return the value in the first column instead of the second one.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post an example, how to use index with VLookup?

Comment: Is this the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659394/vlookup-formula-returns-value-instead-of-the-text-value-it-should-return

Comment: No, they are different questions. That one, I asked about why I got #Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `INDEX` function in combination with `MATCH`?
If I am correct `VLOOKUP` has some limitations where the result column can be.

Documentations: [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: I've never use Index function before. Can you post a solution using index? thanks very much!

Comment: Added the documentations, they are pretty self-explanatory and both have examples.